# SQL Server sqlcmd export/bulk insert issue

Tags: sql-server, bulkinsert, sqlcmd

I'm using sqlcmd to export my data like so -

```
-S Server -dDatabase -E -b -r1 -s "|" -i "D:\Scripts\export.sql" -o \\server\export-YYYYMMDD.csv -h-1
```

It returns a format that contains NULL like so -

```
value1 | value2 | datetime
value2 | NULL   | NULL
value3 | value3 | NULL
```

The NULL actually shows up in the CSV just like that.  NULL.

I can't seem to do a bulk insert.  It keeps failing on those NULL values.  I've tried making a format file.  I'm not sure how to tell it if it sees NULL to insert that value as NULL.

```
USE database;
GO
DELETE table;
GO
BULK INSERT table 
   FROM '\\server\export-YYYYMMDD.csv' 
   WITH (FORMATFILE = '\\server\format.xml');
GO
SELECT * FROM table;
GO
```

If I alter the file and change NULL to '' the insert works fine but I can't do that for the sake of automation.

These databases are not connected whatsoever (separate firewalls) hence the need to export/import.

SHould I be approaching this another way or is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out I was approaching it wrong.

I found the following [documentation](http://www.excel-sql-server.com/sql-server-export-to-excel-using-bcp-sqlcmd-csv.htm) which allowed me to change my export to use BCP instead like so -

```
bcp "select * from dbo.table" queryout test.csv -t, -c -S servername\instance -d Database -T
```

That gave me the data with NULL as blanks which allowed my bulk insert to work correctly.